# Get tabControl SelectedTab From Another Thread Using Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I have tried a few different ways to accomplish this, and none of them are working. I need to get the value of **tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name**. If I try the following code:

```
string name = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name;
```

I get an error that I am *unable to access object from another thread*. So now I am trying to use Invoke to retrieve the value. One of the ways I have found online and tried was the following.

```
string name = tabControl1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Text = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name; })).ToString();
```

This gives the error, *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* I have tried a few other methods, but those resulted in a null result.

I tried searching through SO for an answer to this, but couldn't find anything that worked. I would appreciate any assistance or if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You need to create and manipulate your geometry objects directly on the UI thread. Any thread processing you perform cannot access the geometry object directly they must be dispatched to the thread which created them - the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to do the following:

```
string tab = (string)this.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => controlTab1.SelectedTab.Name));
```

This will return the name of the SelectedTab from the UI thread. Regards.